# How to make nested linear layouts each take up half of parent

Tags: android

Inside of my outer-most layout manager, I've got this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout1" android:layout_weight="1">


    <com.me.android.ui.ImageView
        android:id="@+id/artistimage" android:layout_height="177dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24dp" android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/redtext" android:id="@+id/artistname" />

        <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/artistfav"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:background="@drawable/favbutton"
            android:textOff=" " android:textOn=" " android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:text="Add to Favorites"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Keep in mind that these two `linearlayouts` are nested inside of the outermost layoutmanager, which happens to also be a `linearlayout`. I want to simply have each of the `linearlayout`s that I coped here to take up exactly half of the parent. I thought I could just set the weight of each `linearlayout` manager to 1, but no dice. Right now the image, for example, is taking like 70% of the parent...

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

OK, I changed it to this and the image is taking up half the layout. Nice! But the textview and button disappeared.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout1">


    <com.me.android.ui.ImageView
        android:id="@+id/artistimage" android:layout_height="177dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24dp" android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:textColor="@color/redtext" android:id="@+id/artistname" />

        <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/artistfav"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:background="@drawable/favbutton"
            android:textOff=" " android:textOn=" " android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:text="Add to Favorites"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the outer `LinearLayout` is `horizontal`, set the `android:layout_width` of its children to `0dip`. Then, `android:layout_weight` alone will control the sizing.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Just to make sure we're clear. These two linearlayouts are nested inside of yet another linearlayout (which I didnt copy in my OP)...

Comment: I'm confused... can't get it to work. set the layout_width of the child `linearlayout` (the vertical one) to `0dip`? or set the `imageview` to `0dip`? Tried all combinations, can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Did you mean set the `layout_width` to `0dip` for the `linearlayouts` and then set a `layout_weight` on those layouts? If I do that, everything disappears...

Comment: @LuxuryMode: See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Containers/LinearPercent

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is what worked for me:

```
    <com.me.android.ui.ImageView
        android:id="@+id/artistimage" android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="22dp" android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/redtext" android:id="@+id/artistname"/>

        <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/artistfav"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:background="@drawable/favbutton"
            android:textOff=" " android:textOn=" " android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" 
             />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have specified the width of textview and button to 0 so that explains why they aren't visible